# Can't uninstall Python 3.4.2 from Windows 7 after system restore

Tags: python, windows-7, uninstallation, python-3.4, system-restore

A couple of days after uninstalling Python 3.4.2 I had to carry out a system restore (I'm using Windows 7) due to accidentally installing a bunch of rubbish-ware that was messing with my computer even after installation. This system restore effectively "reinstalled" Python, or rather a broken version of it. I now can't uninstall it via the usual Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs tool, nor can I reinstall it using the original installer. Unfortunately Windows has not saved an earlier system snapshot that I could restore to.

Both the uninstall and reinstall processes make a fair bit of progress before stopping with a warning error that says: "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might succeed in this uninstallation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just delete the `c:\Python3.4\` directory, Reinstall python 3.4 (any sub version, just has to be 3.4), and uninstall that.

Python is, for the most part, totally self-contained in the Python3.4 directory.  Reinstalling python is only needed so you can get a fresh uninstaller to remove the registry keys installation creates.

Comment: Worked a treat! Sorry for slow reply. For some reason I didn't receive notice of your helpful answer.

Answer (score 15):

Just had this problem and solved it by hitting repair first then uninstall.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason that didn't work for me at the time. Only manually deleting the Python directory (as proposed above) worked for me.

Comment: I had to repair by launching the MSI of the appropriate version of Python and running repair from there, then uninstall by launching the MSI again. I'm not sure why this was different than doing it in the control panel, but doing it via a freshly downloaded .msi of the same version of python I had installed just worked. This worked even after deleting the directories and presumably cleaned the extra registry keys.