# Can't uninstall Python 2.7.11, have I screwed up everything?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, anaconda

I'm an anaconda user, but I had to install python 3 a while back in order to use PIP to install a module for whatever reason. And I also had installed python 2.7 but completely forgot about it. Of course, a whole bunch of issues sprouted up from this, namely when trying to run scripts out of the IDLE.

This is the issue that pops up:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run
>   as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support
>   personnel or package vendor.

I downloaded the python 2.7 installer and tried reinstalling it and changing the installation, though that process went smoothly, nothing changed.

The previous answers say that python 3 and anaconda should be uninstalled, which I've done, but the problem persists. What do?

Comment: This is more of a technical support question rather than a programming question, it should be a better fit at Super User. Have you tried *reinstalling* Python 2.7.11 (using an MSI package) to repair any issues and then uninstalling it again?

Comment: Yeah, I used the repair and change installation functions.

Comment: Search on how to force uninstall an MSI package and then use that to get rid of the broken installation.

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629379/cant-uninstall-python-3-4-2-from-windows-7-after-system-restore?rq=1

Comment: I've done that, removed the python27 file but the problem persists.

Comment: It's still not working, maybe the uninstaller doesn't remove everything

Comment: Try removing the registry keys in an elevated command prompt,  `reg delete HKCU\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7 /f` and `reg delete HKLM\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7 /f /reg:32` and `reg delete HKLM\Software\Python\PythonCore\2.7 /f /reg:64`. Probably only one of these commands will succeed. Also, remove the installation directory, e.g. if it was installed in "C:\Python27" run `rmdir /q /s C:\Python27`. Next reinstall 2.7 *without pip*, and then uninstall it.

Answer (score 3):

I had run into this issue some months ago and had given up on it. However reading some comments you got, I realized one could download https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/ => msi or which ever fits your situation. Repair. And then remove.

BR,

/J

Comment: Yeah, this is fantastic advice - Which ever version you have on your machine, and your struggling to repair / change / remove... Go to the link above, and download the installer for the version you already have. Going through the repair steps on this one works. You're then free to remove it.